# How to query sub document in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am having following collection which contains a list of program and each program containing a list of sessions:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f6fd8a4490a19b42c84eb"),
    "Name" : "Program1",
    "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2",
    "Sessions" : [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("544a00716c6d791820c2d1ae"),
        "Name" : "Session1",
        "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2"
    },{
        "_id" : ObjectId("544e426dbb63bc0d94d7ad81"),
        "Name" : "Session2",
        "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2"
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544e42a1bb63bc0d94d7ad82"),
    "Name" : "Program2",
    "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2",
    "Sessions" : [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("543f6fd8a4490a19b42c84eb"),
        "Name" : "Session1",
        "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2"
    },{
        "_id" : ObjectId("544e4cb1bb63bc0d24333b04"),
        "Name" : "Session2",
        "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2"
    }]
}
```

Now for querying program I simply do following:

```
var program = _db.GetCollection<Program>("Program");
IMongoQuery _query = Query<Program>.Where(e => e.Name.Contains("Program"));
programCursor = MongoCursor program.Find(_query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("Name")).SetLimit(ItemsPerPage).SetSkip(ItemsPerPage * (PageNo - 1));
```

Now what if I want to query the sessions which is a sub document. Assuming I've program Id and session name, How will I query the sub document in mongodb c#. I didn't found much help on this scenario that's why I am posting this SO.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
IMongoQuery _query1 = Query<Program>.ElemMatch(e => e.Sessions, builder => builder.Matches(session => session.Name, "/.*" + search_phrase + ".*/"));
```

or

```
IMongoQuery _query2 = Query<Program>.ElemMatch(e => e.Sessions, builder => builder.Where(session => session.Name.Contains(search_phrase)));
```

and you can **And** , **Or** for your queries

```
var query = Query.Or(new BindingList<IMongoQuery>
{
    _query,
    _query1,
    ....
});
```

var result = program.Find(query);

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Following Query:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("543f6fd8a4490a19b42c84eb"),"Sessions.Name":"Session2"}
```

Output:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("543f6fd8a4490a19b42c84eb"),
  "Name" : "Program1",
  "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2",
  "Sessions" : [{
      "_id" : ObjectId("544a00716c6d791820c2d1ae"),
      "Name" : "Session1",
      "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2"
    }, {
      "_id" : ObjectId("544e426dbb63bc0d94d7ad81"),
      "Name" : "Session2",
      "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2"
    }]
}
```

Or can use aggregation to get single session object:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$Sessions" },
    { $match : {"_id" : ObjectId("543f6fd8a4490a19b42c84eb"),"Sessions.Name":"Session2"} }
]);
```

Output:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("543f6fd8a4490a19b42c84eb"),
            "Name" : "Program1",
            "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2",
            "Sessions" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("544e426dbb63bc0d94d7ad81"),
                "Name" : "Session2",
                "Tags" : "Tag1,Tag2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```